# Add values and columns in specific order to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

In `Pandas`, how do I add values to a `DataFrame` with columns that are set in a specific order?

I have tried various things with different erroneous results.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([a, b, c], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

> ValueError: ('Shape of passed values is (..., ...), indices imply (..., ...)', u'occurred at index 0')

```
df = pd.DataFrame([a], [b], [c], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

> TypeError: ('**init**() takes at most 6 arguments (... given)', u'occurred at index 0')

`a`, `b`, `c` are simply strings:

```
a = "string a"
b = "string b"
c = "string c"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a list of lists , which each list having three elements, that are values for the three columns , hence each inner list would resemble a row. Example -

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[a, b, c]], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

Comment: Thanks Anand! Not knowing that I was supposed to use double brackets for the data kept me looking for solutions for 1,5 hour :) In retrospect it was pretty obvious. Thank you.